# Can we send unsigned client certificates with HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I have seen code samples of how to use `WebRequestHandler` with `HttpClient` to embed a certificate in my http request (see snippet below). However, I just tested this with a self-signed cert and it is not working. According to [this post](https://voicumatei.wordpress.com/2014/05/15/use-x509-certificate-for-client-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api/) this method will not work without a trusted certificate.

I can see the certificate on the server if I send it through the browser or Postman, but not programmatically.

Can someone confirm or deny if `HttpClient` or `WebRequestHandler`perform any kind of certificate validation before sending it as part of the request?

A quick de-compile did not show anything obvious, but there are many things in play along the request pipeline.

Sample code:

```
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(rawCert);


        //This call fails, cannot check revocation authority.
        //Specific error: The revocation function was unable to check
        //revocation for the certificate.
        //X509CertificateValidator.ChainTrust.Validate(cert);

        var certHandler = new WebRequestHandler()
        {
            ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false
        };
        certHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
        var Certificateclient = new HttpClient(certHandler)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("https://web.local")
        };

        var response = await Certificateclient.GetAsync("somepath");
```

Comment: You can send anything but an unsigned one won't be trusted by the receiver.

Comment: Have you personally verified that statement? That is not the behavior I am observing in the code sample above (nor the behavior observer by the author of the blog I posted). If you have been able to do so, then our hypothesis is incorrect and the issue is somewhere else -- however, using a trusted cert was a solution for the blogger.

Comment: A self signed cert is inherently untrustworthy on its own. Do you just want something that works with the HTTPS protocol, but doesn't convey who the client is (in a trustworthy way)? Or are you looking to build a solution using internally signed certs (not signed by a CA)? If it's the former, and you have control of the web server you could (depending on which web server) tell it to ignore client authentication. If the later then you need to place the signing cert (which could be the client cert itself) in the web server's cert store. If you don't have control of web server you're out of luck.

Comment: I want to make development simple. I should be able to use self signed  certificates during my development process.

Comment: @MauricioAviles self signed certificates are commonly used in development, and I have personally used them. It would be easy to configure them on developers' machine, but no other machines will trust them unless manually configured. That's what I mean. The way you generates the certificates and the way you configure them matters a lot, but you described too little about how you did. That makes it impossible to help out as no one can touch your machines but yourself.

Comment: In this case the self-signed certificate was issue by a root authority that is trusted by the dev machine. However, the X509CertificateValidator.ChainTrust.Validate(cert) fails because it is unable to contact the revocation for the certificate. I'll add this information to the question, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

To use a self signed cert, you can add `using System.Net.Security;`

add a handler callback method

```
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

and set before invoke the API:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
```

See:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/153207/86150

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/130308da-4092-4f21-8355-ee3c77a22f97/llamar-web-service-con-certificado?forum=netfxwebes